# Why doesn't "brew cleanup" or "brew cleanup -n" show any output?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I would love to clean my device of any homebrew update or version copies and then I figured that the command used for that would be

```
brew cleanup
```

and if I wanted to check how much of storage it would clear, the command would be

```
brew cleanup -n
brew cleanup --dry-run
```

None of them seem to work for me, and I want to clear my computer of any extra useless copies of Homebrew.

Also, would it be possible that it is actually happening but it is not showing me any output?

Here is the output:

```
temp@Apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew cleanup -n
temp@Apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew cleanup   
temp@Apples-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

All I need is some output showing how much space can be cleared / is cleared when I run the command.

Would it be possible that since I installed home-brew just yesterday, there is nothing to delete and hence this output?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is too broad, does not describe a sufficient problem and hence should not be on the board.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's probably because there is nothing to clean up.
Especially if you've only had Homebrew for 1 day.

> I want to clear my computer of any extra useless copies of Homebrew.

That's not what `brew cleanup` is for. It's for deleting old and unused files downloaded by Homebrew during `brew install`. It's *not* for clearing old versions of Homebrew (that is automatically done when you do `brew update`).

```
~$ brew cleanup --help
Usage: brew cleanup [options] [formula|cask]

Remove stale lock files and outdated downloads for all formulae and casks, and
remove old versions of installed formulae. If arguments are specified, only do
this for the given formulae and casks. Removes all downloads more than 120 days
old. This can be adjusted with HOMEBREW_CLEANUP_MAX_AGE_DAYS.

      --prune                      Remove all cache files older than specified
                                   days.
  -n, --dry-run                    Show what would be removed, but do not
                                   actually remove anything.
  -s                               Scrub the cache, including downloads for
                                   even the latest versions. Note downloads
                                   for any installed formulae or casks will
                                   still not be deleted. If you want to delete
                                   those too: rm -rf "$(brew --cache)"
      --prune-prefix               Only prune the symlinks and directories
                                   from the prefix and remove no other files.
```

Notice the part of "*Removes all downloads more than 120 days
old.*". If you haven't installed that many things with Homebrew and/or you have not been using it for a long time, then it's expected that there is nothing to clean up. Also, even with the `-s` option, Homebrew does not delete files for "*any installed formulae or casks*".

Try installing and uninstall something, then do `brew cleanup`:

```
~$ brew install grep amazon-ecs-cli iterm2
...

~$ brew cleanup -s -n
~$
~$ brew uninstall grep amazon-ecs-cli iterm2
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/grep/3.6... (21 files, 964.6KB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/amazon-ecs-cli/1.21.0... (7 files, 46.2MB)
==> Uninstalling Cask iterm2
==> Backing App 'iTerm.app' up to '/usr/local/Caskroom/iterm2/3.4.3/iTerm.app'.
==> Removing App '/Applications/iTerm.app'.
==> Purging files for version 3.4.3 of Cask iterm2

~$ brew cleanup -s -n
Would remove: /Users/me/Library/Caches/Homebrew/amazon-ecs-cli--1.21.0.catalina.bottle.tar.gz (14.8MB)
Would remove: /Users/me/Library/Caches/Homebrew/grep--3.6.catalina.bottle.tar.gz (330.8KB)
Would remove: /Users/me/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/iterm2--3.4.3.zip (21.3MB)
==> This operation would free approximately 36.4MB of disk space.
```

Notice that doing `brew cleanup` while those formulae are installed, it does not show any output. Only when they are uninstalled does it become something to clean.

Or try passing in the `--prune=1` option (remove all cache files older than 1 day) and the `-s` option (scrub the cache, even for latest versions). On my system where I've had Homebrew for years:

```
~$ brew cleanup --prune=1 -s -n
...
==> This operation would free approximately 1.1GB of disk space.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I now understand that brew cleanup is not used to clear old versions of home-brew itself.

Also, I did this ```brew cleanup --prune=1 -s -n``` and it worked. 

I just have one last query....

If I perform this command will everything I installed using home-brew stop working or will only the older copies of it stop working?

Comment: @RajatShenoi It should only delete unused, uninstalled files. You have to understand that when brew installs something, it first downloads stuff on your machine, then compiles/builds and copies the appropriate files to the correct locations. These files during download, these are the ones to be cleaned up. If you installed something, then updated it to a new version, it will cleanup the download files *of the old version*. If you uninstalled `something`, it will cleanup the files it originally downloaded for that `something`.

Comment: @RajatShenoi Basically, doing `brew cleanup` should not cause existing formula you installed with Homebrew to stop working. If something did, then that's a bug, and you can report that to Homebrew or the formula author/s.

Comment: Question of a newbie: if I install something with brew, it downloads a file and makes copies. But these downloaded files are of no use. Why doesn't cleanup delete them? As you explain, it only cleans them when uninstalled.